# How to extract a value after colon in all the rows from a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Edit: the dummy dataframe is edited

I have a pandas data frame with the below kind of column with 200 rows.

Let's say the name of df is data.

```
-----------------------------------|
B
-----------------------------------|
{'animal':'cat', 'bird':'peacock'...}
```

I want to extract the value of animal to a separate column C for all the rows.

I tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
data['C'] = data["B"].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[-2] if ':' in x else x)
```

Please help.

Comment: please provide the output of `data['B'].head().to_dict()`, it is currently ambiguous

Comment: Considering it a sensitive data, I am unable to share the output. however, I can see that it is getting converted into a dictionary

Comment: Can you transform the output you have in dummy data keeping exactly the same format? And please provide the matching (dummy) expected output

Comment: It's in this form:

`{0: {'animal': 'cat',
     'bird': 'peacock'} `

Comment: Then does `df['B'].str['animal']` give you what you want?

Comment: It's returning the None
`0      None
1      None
2      None`

Comment: Then, the example you provided is not well crafted. You **must** provide a reproducible example, else you're wasting everyone's time and the question should rather be closed.

Comment: @mozway You seem to have trouble with explaining the idea and concept of a [mre]. You should not try;  and link instead. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch trouble? I'd rather say weariness… this [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) link is more appropriate for pandas ;)

Comment: Perfect. I did not know there are tailored explanations, but if you know one, use it. Just if you interested, I made one for Sqlite, found at the tag wiki for sqlite. (So yes, I kind of did know ... that there is one for Sqlite ;-) )

Comment: Well, I answer many times from my phone, it's not always practical to go fetch the links. anyway enough offtopic. I'll just vote to close as OP doesn't provide reproducible data.

Comment: Yunnosch, Thank you. @mozway, thank you for your help and patience. Seems like I was dealing with a nested dictionary, I am getting the correct output now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary is unpacked with pd.json_normalize

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'B': [{0: {'animal': 'cat', 'bird': 'peacock'}}]})

data['C'] = pd.json_normalize(data['B'])['0.animal']
```

Comment: It's a waste when you can use `df['B'].str['animal']` directly ;)

Comment: Clean. Else have to fetch the right output in two lines of code.

Comment: @mozway df['B'].str['animal'] returns None

Comment: @Сергей my bad, `df['B'].str[0].str['animal']`

Comment: Yes, because "animal"  was  in a nested dictionary.

Comment: @Ann09 please update your question to provide the reproducible example

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope its all ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of the structure of your data. Does this look right?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "B": ["'animal':'cat'", "'bird':'peacock'"]
})

df["C"] = df.B.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r".*?\:(.*$)", r"\1", x))
```

Comment: Hi, It currently throws an error.  `expected string or bytes-like object`
The dataset type is pandas.core.series.Series.

Comment: yeah it looks like the data is formatted differently. Can you update with exactly how the data is formatted? Maybe make a dummy dataset like I did here.